# Rails link_to path with dynamic variable (read from database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently developing a Rails Application with a large set of engines.

I have some paths to Engines root-path stored in a database.

However, if I try to link to them using the value from the database (it's stored in the 'root_path'-Field) and the link_to helper in the view I don't get the correct link.

Here's an example (assume that the `root_path` in the database is currently `foo_engine.bar_path`)

```
- @engines.each do |engine|
  = link_to engine.name, engine.root_path
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:3000/foo_engine.bar_path
```

I get

```
http://localhost:3000/current_engine/foo_engine.bar_path
```

Thank you in advance

Philipp

Comment: can you do `rake routes` in the terminal and post the result?

Comment: Thank you!
The problem is that I want to route to a different engine and the path to the engine is stored in the database.

Comment: Glad the problem is fixed!

Comment: Ah sorry. I just want to say thank you that you tried to help me :-) The problem is still there :-D

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
I've found a solution for this one.

Just use

```
- @engines.each do |engine|
  = link_to engine.name, eval(engine.root_path)
```

But eval is evil. Is there another way?

Comment: I think this use of `eval` is safe. You are not using `eval` on user submitted content. Have you tried `"/#{engine.root_path}"`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I just have tried your suggestion. "#/{engine.root_path}". Unfortunately it's not working since the conversion from the helper-Method to the url get's not triggered.